# INSERT if not exists, else return id

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

There are some limitations:

1. Cannot modify database
2. Columns are not unique
3. Needs to return last insert id (`RETURNING id`)
4. If exists, return existing id
5. It will be called through our custom db library (the values in select will be as parameters from PHP (?, ?, ?, !))

```
INSERT INTO tags (name, color, groupid)
SELECT  'test', '000000', 56
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT text FROM tags WHERE name = 'test' AND groupid = 56
)
RETURNING id
```

This works - until to the point where i need to get existing id aswell. With this i only get the inserted id.
Is it possible to return the value of SELECT statement if  it doesn't insert?

UPDATE:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT text FROM tags WHERE name = 'test' AND groupid = 56
    )
    THEN
      INSERT INTO tags (name, color, groupid)
          VALUES  ('test', '000000', 56) RETURNING id;
    ELSE
      RETURN SELECT text FROM tags WHERE name = 'test' AND groupid = 56;
    END IF;
END
$$
```

Was testing with this kind of format - however this ends with a few errors:

```
RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning void
```

Comment: You can avoid that last error by making a named function rather than a `DO` statement, with exactly the same body, e.g. `CREATE FUNCTION foo(text, text, int) RETURNS int LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ ....`; then you'd execute it as `SELECT foo(?, ?, ?) AS id`

Comment: For testing i created it as a function, result is a just ta bit different: ´ERROR: query has no destination for result data´

Comment: That's because the `RETURNING id` is like a `SELECT`, you need to tell the function to `RETURN` the result of the whole `INSERT` statement, I think.

Comment: hi i'm not very familiar with PostgreSql but i have some free time and come up with this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9f96a so you can chack if it's work for you, this will insert new value and return value -1 if value is not exists in table already and if there is a value it will return value id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a CTE.

The info cte has the source data, so replace the values there with your placeholders for PHP.

The CTE will return the results from the first half of the union if an existing record exists (so will show old id), and the second half if an insert was performed (so will show the new id).

```
WITH info (name, color, groupid) AS
  (values('test','000000',56)),
  trial AS (
    INSERT INTO tags(name, color, groupid)
      SELECT info.name, info.color, info.groupid
      FROM info
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM tags t2
        WHERE t2.name = info.name AND t2.groupid= info.groupid)
    RETURNING id)
SELECT tags.id
FROM tags
INNER JOIN info ON tags.name = info.name AND tags.groupid= info.groupid
UNION ALL
SELECT trial.id
FROM trial;
```

SQL Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a7b0f/2

Postgres manual page for using CTEs

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html

Comment: almost - it works fine in pgadmin, calling it out through php however:

ERROR: column &quot;groupid&quot; is of type integer but expression is of type text LINE 6: SELECT  info.name,  info.color,  info.groupid ^ HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

And i don't see why.

Comment: Sounds like your PHP code is sending a text string into the group id column.  If you're sure its an int and can't change the PHP to send an int, it can be fixed by changing the values line with something like:   (values( :name,:color,cast(:groupid as int))

Comment: indeed it managed to  send it as a string. To make sure i added ::integer casting on each of those.

Answer (score -2):

You can use an IF statement to do this.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT text FROM tags WHERE name = 'test')
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tags (name, color, groupid)
  VALUES ('test', '000000', 56)
  SET @textId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT @textId = ID FROM tags WHERE name = 'test'
END
```

You have to make necessary changes in above query as per your requirements.

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"

That doesn't even look as a valid syntax.

Shouldn't it be IF THAN ELSE ?

Comment: This looks like Microsoft SQLServer syntax

Answer (score -3):

if `name` is unique:

```
INSERT INTO `tags` (name, color, groupid) VALUES ('test', '000000', 56)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), `name`='test';
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: Name is not unique. There can be multiple identical names BUT have different groupid. So the whole insert/select check is in the "scope" of that group.

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY doesn't exist in PostgreSQL, your query would fail. It would also fail on other issues on your specific MySQL query.